# How do I take input and save it into multiple variables

Tags: python, input

I am trying to take a string input (3 2) and save it into 2 variables.

```
n,k = map(int, input(), split(' '))
```

But this gives me an error:

NameError: name 'split' is not defined

Comment: Split is not a function, it's a method on a string object. You're currently trying to call it and pass what it returns as the third argument to map.

Answer (score 2):

`split` isn't a builtin function, it's a method of strings.

```
n, k = map(int, input().split())
```